# Как написать такой цикл?

Tags: php

Как написать такой цикл, чтоб он заменял у строки последний элемент на 1?
То есть, к примеру мы имеем переменную `$url = 'url,com/films?page='` В конце этой строки по дефолту стоит число 1. Нужен цикл `for`, который будет заменять это число на единицу больше. Как такое сделать?
Вот что я сделал:

```
$url = 'url,com/films?page=';
for($i=1;$i<10;$i++){
 $url .= $i;
}
```

Но это просто конкатенация и результат будет `url,com/films?page=123456789`
А нужно чтоб было `url,com/films?page=1` `url,com/films?page=2`  `url,com/films?page=3` Как такого результата добиться?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *нужно чтоб было url,com/films?page=1 url,com/films?page=2  url,com/films?page=3*

Собирайте урлы в массив, используя конкатенацию но без модификации исходного url:

```
$url = 'url.com/films?page=';
$links = [];

for ($i = 1; $i < 10; $i++) {
    $links[] = $url . $i;
}

var_dump($links);
```

Comment: Вроде правильно, но затем мне нужно каждый url использовать уже в другой функции, получается после этого мне нужно использовать foreach?

Comment: @Евгений а что вам нужно было в итоге, просто вывести все эти урлы в браузер?

Comment: Нет. В итоге мне эти url нужны для парсера. Я получаю эти url и каждый url нужно будет парсить

Comment: @Евгений ну тогда я правильно предположил, собрав их в массиве. А что дальше с ними делать, и каким циклом обрабатывать - будет зависеть от задачи, которая скорее всего уже выходит за рамки этого топика.

Comment: Все равно, спасибо)